# Xrdp startup failure

Tags: xrdp

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS.  I had xrdp working properly then I ran out of diskspace and Ubuntu did some crazy stuff to make sure it could still boot.  I have gotten the system up and running again and freed up disk space.  The only thing that still does not work is xrdp.  I have tried removing it completely, restarting then reisntalling given many instruction that I have found googling.  It still does not work.  Here is what I get.

```
Setting up xrdp (0.6.1-2) ...
Job for xrdp.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status xrdp.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript xrdp, action "start" failed.
● xrdp.service - xrdp daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/xrdp.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-06-15 08:33:53 CDT; 6ms ago
     Docs: man:xrdp(8)
           man:xrdp.ini(5)
  Process: 5051 ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/xrdp $XRDP_OPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 15 08:33:53 GitLabServer systemd[1]: Starting xrdp daemon...
Jun 15 08:33:53 GitLabServer systemd[1]: xrdp.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 15 08:33:53 GitLabServer systemd[1]: Failed to start xrdp daemon.
Jun 15 08:33:53 GitLabServer systemd[1]: xrdp.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 15 08:33:53 GitLabServer systemd[1]: xrdp.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
dpkg: error processing package xrdp (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up tightvncserver (1.3.10-0ubuntu3) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/tightvncserver to provide /usr/bin/vncserver (vncserver) in auto mode
update-alternatives: renaming Xvnc.1.gz slave link from /usr/share/man/man1/Xvnc.1.gz to /usr/share/man/man1/Xvnc
Errors were encountered while processing:
 xrdp
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Then

```
$ journalctl -xe
Subject: Unit xrdp.service has begun start-up
Defined-By: systemd
Support: 

Unit xrdp.service has begun starting up.
Jun 15 08:33:53 GitLabServer systemd[1]: xrdp.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 15 08:33:53 GitLabServer systemd[1]: Failed to start xrdp daemon.
Subject: Unit xrdp.service has failed
Defined-By: systemd

Unit xrdp.service has failed.

The result is failed.
Jun 15 08:33:53 GitLabServer systemd[1]: xrdp.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 15 08:33:53 GitLabServer systemd[1]: xrdp.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 15 08:33:53 GitLabServer systemd[1]: Stopping xrdp session manager...
Subject: Unit xrdp-sesman.service has begun shutting down
Defined-By: systemd

Unit xrdp-sesman.service has begun shutting down.
Jun 15 08:33:53 GitLabServer systemd[1]: Stopped xrdp session manager.
Subject: Unit xrdp-sesman.service has finished shutting down
Defined-By: systemd
Support: 

Unit xrdp-sesman.service has finished shutting down.
Jun 15 08:33:56 GitLabServer sudo[4334]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jun 15 08:34:23 GitLabServer smbd[5124]: pam_unix(samba:session): session closed for user nobody
Jun 15 08:34:23 GitLabServer smbd[5125]: pam_unix(samba:session): session closed for user nobody
Jun 15 08:35:01 GitLabServer CRON[5234]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jun 15 08:35:01 GitLabServer CRON[5235]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Jun 15 08:35:01 GitLabServer CRON[5234]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jun 15 08:40:38 GitLabServer systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
Subject: Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has begun start-up
Defined-By: systemd

Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has begun starting up.
Jun 15 08:40:38 GitLabServer systemd-tmpfiles[6017]: [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/var.conf:14] Duplicate line for path "/var/log
Jun 15 08:40:38 GitLabServer systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Subject: Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has finished start-up
Defined-By: systemd
```

Any help you can give me would be great as I am at a loss.

Thank you
Andy